# Getting RFID scan with flutter - Zebra device

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am trying to implement this [plugin](https://github.com/ZebraDevs/DataWedge-Flutter-Demo) on an MC3300X scanner. I was able to get the barcode however my intent is to use this scanner for RFID. I was recommended to change  `createDataWedgeProfile` to enable the RFID plugin and also modify the `createDataWedgeBroadcastReceiver` to reflect the format of the received Intent. The issue is I can't find any example code related to RFID on Zebra website, so I am not sure what decode mode to use. I tried `smart_decode_type` and `decode_data` mode for `scanData`, but both return `null` as the result. Do you guys think this is possible? What should I do now?

> ```
> private fun createDataWedgeBroadcastReceiver(events: EventSink?): BroadcastReceiver? {
>     return object : BroadcastReceiver() {
>         override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
>             if (intent.action.equals(PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION))
>             {
>                 //  A barcode has been scanned
>
>                 var scanData =intent.getStringExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_DATA_STRING)
>
>                 var symbology = intent.getStringExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_LABEL_TYPE)
>                 var date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
>                 var df = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
>                 var dateTimeString = df.format(date)
>                 var currentScan = Scan(scanData,   symbology, dateTimeString);
>                 events?.success(currentScan.toJson())
>             }
>             //  Could handle return values from DW here such as RETURN_GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE
>             //  or RETURN_ENUMERATE_SCANNERS
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> private fun createDataWedgeProfile(profileName: String) {
>     //  Create and configure the DataWedge profile associated with this application
>     //  For readability's sake, I have not defined each of the keys in the DWInterface file
>     dwInterface.sendCommandString(this, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_CREATE_PROFILE, profileName)
>     val profileConfig = Bundle()
>     profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_NAME", profileName)
>     profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true") //  These are all strings
>     profileConfig.putString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE")
>     val barcodeConfig = Bundle()
>     barcodeConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE")
>     barcodeConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true") //  This is the default but never hurts to specify
>     val barcodeProps = Bundle()
>     barcodeConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", barcodeProps)
>     profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", barcodeConfig)
>     val appConfig = Bundle()
>     appConfig.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", packageName)      //  Associate the profile with this app
>     appConfig.putStringArray("ACTIVITY_LIST", arrayOf("*"))
>     profileConfig.putParcelableArray("APP_LIST", arrayOf(appConfig))
>     dwInterface.sendCommandBundle(this, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig)
>     //  You can only configure one plugin at a time in some versions of DW, now do the intent output
>     profileConfig.remove("PLUGIN_CONFIG")
>     val intentConfig = Bundle()
>     intentConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "INTENT")
>     intentConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
>     val intentProps = Bundle()
>     intentProps.putString("intent_output_enabled", "true")
>     intentProps.putString("intent_action", PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION)
>     intentProps.putString("intent_delivery", PROFILE_INTENT_BROADCAST)  //  "2"
>     intentConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", intentProps)
>     profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", intentConfig)
>     dwInterface.sendCommandBundle(this, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig)
> }
> ```

Update: For anyone who is facing the same issue, editing the profile through the DataWedge app alone will not work. What I did was to add these to `createDataWedgeProfile` to enable the RFID plugin.

```
    val rfidConfigParamList = Bundle()
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_input_enabled", "true")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_beeper_enable", "true")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_led_enable", "true")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_antenna_transmit_power", "30")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_memory_bank", "2")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_session", "1")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_trigger_mode", "1")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_filter_duplicate_tags", "true")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_hardware_trigger_enabled", "true")
    rfidConfigParamList.putString("rfid_tag_read_duration", "250")


    val rfidConfigBundle = Bundle()
    rfidConfigBundle.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "RFID")
    rfidConfigBundle.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    rfidConfigBundle.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", rfidConfigParamList)
    profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", rfidConfigParamList)
```

Comment: Plugin author here: I thought the output was in data_string, have you tried that?  I can't find any examples of output either and I don't have the hardware myself I'm afraid.  Let me ask internally.  For specifying the input parameters please see here: https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/11-0/guide/api/setconfig/#setrfidinputconfiguration

Comment: Thank you, output for the barcode is in data_string. However, I can't retrieve any output when scanning an RFID tag. That's why I thought it may be in another format. I enable the RFID input in datawedge app manually though, since I don't know how to change it in "createDataWedgeProfile". Could that be an issue?

Comment: I used the link you provided and it works now. Looks like manually edit the profile on the data wedge app will not work. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data will be delivered as String. If multiple tags are read they will be concatenated and send in a single intent.

https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/11-0/guide/output/intent/

Tag: DATA_STRING_TAG

Type: [String]

Name: "com.symbol.datawedge.data_string"

Contents: Acquired barcode characters

Example: "abcde12345"